# Assign Variable inside ng-repeat with ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I trying to make a pagination system but I have problems when I try update my `CurrentPage Variable`, when I try to make a `<li ng-click="currentPage"....` the variable no update please check this fragment http://jsfiddle.net/f17sLojb/3/

**note: I need work only in html side, I dont want make a function in javascript for fix it**, 
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a hierarchy to the variable inside the ng-repeat because the ng-repeat has its own scope.  check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f17sLojb/2/)

```
<div ng-init="numPagin=5;page.currentPage=1"></div>

ng-click="page.currentPage=$index+1"
```